# SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in Yii2

Tags: ssl, yii2, gmail, swiftmailer

A time ago, i could use my gmail adress to receive and send messages using swift mailer in yii2. I don't remember to made any change, but now i got the:

> SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
>   error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate
>   verify failed

My swift mail settings:

```
'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
                'username' => 'mymailadress@gmail.com',
                'password' => 'mypassword',
                'port' => '465',
                'encryption' => 'ssl',
                'streamOptions' => [ 
            'ssl' => [ 
                'allow_self_signed' => true,
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
```

I have the `adminEmail` changed in both the front and the backend.
My google setting are good, the: **Access for less secure apps setting has been turned on** and i enabled the  IMAP. I don't know what i do wrong. I tried to use a new gmail or to change the settings in the swift maileg configuration to tls.

Answer (score 0):

> 'transport' => [
>
> 'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
>
> 'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
>
> 'username' => 'mymailadress',
>
> 'password' => 'mypassword',
>
> 'port' => 587,
>
> 'encryption' => 'tls',
>
> ],

try to use tls instead, and no need to fill username with `@gmail.com`